# Find files containing text using grep command starts with file name charector

Tags: linux, unix, putty

I want find the file containing some text but that should start with some character.

```
grep -inr "my text" .
```

The above command will show all the files containing the above text. But what I want is if the file contains a text and the name should starts with like E*.

Comment: You mean the name of the file starting with `E` or the line starting with `E`?

Comment: Name of the file starting with 'E'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this,

```
find . -name 'E*' -exec grep -Hl "sample" {} \;
```

**Explanation:**

`-H` : Print the file name for each match.

`-l` : Suppress  normal  output

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `find` and `grep`:

```
find . -name "E*" | xargs grep -nH "my text"
```

You can also use `find`s `exec` parameter instead of `xargs`. Take a look at its man mange for this: `man find`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a max-depth for 1 layer, then i think most efficient way would be...

```
grep <pattern> E*
```

for multiple levels you can use like this

```
grep <pattern> */*/E*
```

Comment: This is a *very* shaky solution at best: 1) Parsing `ls`s output is highly discouraged. (In fact that command failed miserably on my machine.) 2) This won't work for filenames with spaces.

Comment: works on my machine fine.... + as far as my knownledge goes you cant create file names with spaces

Comment: The format of `ls`s output depends on the locale, which is why it may work on one machine and not the other, which in turn is why it's a bad idea. And that you can't create filenames with spaces is just preposterous; it's possible and even very common.

Comment: changed it, why at all use `ls` :)

Comment: oh i take back what I said.. you can create a file name with space. Just came to know about it. Thanks :). Above command works for it....